# how to show live server of react once closing command line

Tags: reactjs, command-line, command

I am trying to create my first react app. I've done a fair bit of work but then closed the command line prompt window. I now cant see any of my work and it says Hmmm... cant reach this page. localhost refused to connect.

How do I get my live server back for react please!

Answer (score 1):

You can open `package.json`, on `scripts` part and you will see command to build react by type it on command line.

In your case, I think you can try `npm start`

Answer (score 1):

Goto the project folder, now press **shift** with **right mouse key**

[image],

open PowerShell then write

```
npm start
```